# Sencha Touch : Querying an object to see if a component exists

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, component-query

Basically what Im  trying to do is query a component for a button without having to do a global component query. I have a menuPanel which contains a button with an "Id" of a Guid as shown below.

> var test1 = menuPanel.query('button[id="38eb85fd-c18e-4a2d-a382-881732c732f9"]')[0];

When I log the above I get the correct object which returns me the GUID above as expected.

However, the code below logs "Undefined"

> var test2 = menuPanel.query('button[id="'+record.get('Id')+'"]')[0];

Any ideas what Ive missed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tis looks correct. Are you sure that `record.get('Id')`returns what you expect ?

Comment: The console log for record.get('Id') returns me "38eb85fd-c18e-4a2d-a382-881732c732f9" as expected